# converting C++ structure to C# structure at build time

Tags: c#, c++, structure, marshalling

So here's the background:
We have a legacy program that writes data logs in C++.  the data is contained in different structures.  The program that reads the log files uses those same structures to display the data.  I rewrote the program that reads the log files and C# and had to create C# copy of all those structures by hand.
Is there a better way to do this?  I have considered setting up a lookup path to the structures and a sort of parser that would generate a C# structure at build time, but it seems excessively complicated to handle all the special cases.  Are there any suggestions to do this?  it seems kind of ridiculous that C# doesn't have any backwards compatibility to handle C/C++ structures.

Answer (score 1):

How many structures are there and how complicated are they?

It's a costs vs benefits question I'd say. I'll bet that, judging from your question, just quickly coding the structs in C# is the best way to go.

Just my 2 cents, before taxes...

Comment: There are more structures than i want to think about.  There are a lot.  The problem is that if a developer changes the C++ structure, then they HAVE to change the C# structure.  If they don't then we just default to displaying hex data.  If it happens to be a message that is not used frequently, then we may not know until well after the software is released.

Comment: If this is an in-house project, you could of course coordinate with the development team to provide you with a C# version of the structs whenever they change them...

Answer (score 0):

Summary of your problem:
You have a large number of structs in an existing C++ program that you serialize to disk. You want to port the structs to C# so you can deserialize the data from disk into your C# program. You don't just want to do this once. You want to keep the two sets of structs in sync as both programs evolve.

What you need is an [Interface Definition Language (IDL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) in which you can describe your data in a language independent way. Something like [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/).

The steps you'd have to take would be:

1. Convert your existing C++ structs into IDL. This is a one-off process. Use a custom script or look for an existing one. Someone must have solved this by now.
2. Setup your build system to generate both the C# and the C++ definitions at build time.
3. Use the Thrift/ProtoBuf/MessagePack C# and C++ APIs to serialize and deserialize your data as needed.

The disadvantages are:

1. You need build-time code generation. But you already considered this yourself and this way the work has already been done for you.
2. You will have to change both your C++ and C# to correctly use whatever data structures are generated for you.
3. The binary on disk format will change so legacy logs won't be readable. But you can write some C++ to convert them to the new format quite easily.

I think this is outweighed by the advantages:

1. The IDL will contain the canonical description of your data. Any changes to it will be reflected in both your C++ and C#. You won't have to manually update your C# version when the C++ one changes.
2. The binary data format will be machine-independent. You will be able to read/write your data from many different languages on a variety of platforms.
3. The third-party libraries I mentioned are robust and widely used. Better than hacking something yourself.